# margin-left not merging with auto

Tags: html, css

- margin-left: auto seems not working
  1- Header with an image and a navbar
  2- Two unorder list in a navbar
  2- Try to get one of the list on the left side and the second in the right side

If I use margin-left: 800px, it's working however, it's not with auto.

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
header{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 10px 10px;
}
nav{
    font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin-left: 15px;
}
.nav__links_R, .nav__links_L, a {
    text-decoration: none;
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
    color:rgba(0, 0, 0, .50);

}
.nav__links_R {
    margin-left: auto;
}

.nav__links_L li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0px 20px;
}

.nav__links_R li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0px 20px;
}
```

```html
  <header>
        <img src="../photo/logo_dark.png" alt="logo">
        <nav>
            <ul class=nav__links_L>
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class=nav__links_R>
                <li><a href="#">Register</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
```

Everything is displaying well as expecting. Only ".nav__links_R" not going to the right side with "auto"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following two style rules to `nav`:

```
width: 100%;
display: flex;
```

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
header{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 10px 10px;
}
nav{
    font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin-left: 15px;
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
}
.nav__links_R, .nav__links_L, a {
    text-decoration: none;
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
    color:rgba(0, 0, 0, .50);

}
.nav__links_R {
    margin-left: auto;
}

.nav__links_L li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0px 20px;
}

.nav__links_R li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0px 20px;
}
```

```html
 <header>
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/40" alt="logo">
        <nav>
            <ul class=nav__links_L>
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class=nav__links_R>
                <li><a href="">Register</a></li>
                <li><a href="">login</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
```